# How I suppose to break 10 k records in ng-repeat in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show records of 10k in an HTML table using ng-repeat, but when ng-repeat runs, it crashes the browser every time. I need solutions so I can fix it.

I am looking for a solution so I can fix this problem. I need a solution using ng-repeat in a single tbody tag because I am using datatable.

Comment: "50000 k"? So, 50 million records? What human being is going to have the patience to scroll through 50 million rows of a table? (Or 50,000 for that matter?)

Comment: Sorry I have written the wrong entries.

Comment: Any solution how to handle big data in ng-repeat ?

Comment: @SyedYahyaMasood Use pagination. But don't store all the data client-side—it would be ridiculous to need to download 10 million records every time a user visited the page.

Comment: Introduce pagination and show only a certain number of rows. If possible, change api endpoint to accept two parameters: a number of entries and starting index, and on request send those parameters. Change parameters dynamically, based on currently selected page and number of rows a user wants to display.

Comment: Definitely you need to consider pagination to fix your crash problem to reduce the number of records load at a time which improves the performance.

Please check below references, one is using Ng-Table
 
https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-table-pagination-with-ng-table
https://embed.plnkr.co/tWFUPm/

Comment: @SyedYahyaMasood Did you mean 10 000 000 records or 10 000 records?